Install GCC 7.20 on Ubuntu 22.04
I saw this question several years ago, but it is worth asking.
I have to do a coding test on "GCC 7.2.0 (with -std=c++17)" I have in my Ubuntu: "gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)"
They say, "Your solution will be compiled with GCC 7.2.0 (with -std=c++17), and you will have the chance to fix any compilation errors before submission."
Now I have two questions:

Can I install GCC 7.2.0 on my Ubuntu without creating a VM?
Can I  code in my environment and send it? The compiler should have backward compatibility because it should be just an algorithm for an online test, and they are saying: "You may use the standard libraries for the task. It is not permitted to use other libraries. However, you will not need them anyway."?

Thank you!

If you go to gnu.org, you can download the source and build requirements,  read the upper case filenames (INSTALL*, README*, run the configure script with parameters poiniting to your private storage, and compile it yourself. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier. Don't mess with the systtem's files!

Ok, I will do that thank you!
